# Custom Zip exercise from python principles

Tags: python

This is a challenge from python principles site.

Custom zip
The built-in zip function "zips" two lists. Write your own implementation of this function.

Define a function named zap. The function takes two parameters, a and b. These are lists.

Your function should return a list of tuples. Each tuple should contain one item from the a list and one from b.

You may assume a and b have equal lengths.

If you don't get it, think of a zipper.

For example:

```
zap(
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
)
```

Should return:

```
[(0, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 8)]
```

I made this so far:

```
def zap(a, b):
    call_zap = []
    for (i,x) in (a,b):
        call_zap.append((i,x))
    return (call_zap)
```

and got this answer:

> Wrong Submission Your submission was not accepted. Here is an
> explanation:
>
> The call `zap([1, 2], [3, 4])` should return '[(1, 3), (2, 4)]', but it
> returned '[(1, 2), (3, 4)]'

Comment: Your `for (i,x) in (a,b)` doesn't mean what you want. You would need a `zip` call for it to mean what you want, but using `zip` would defeat the point of the exercise.

Comment: I´m a beginner, I need to use range, but tried many things and cannot advance. some tips please

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the site don´t let you use nothing with "zip"
"Your solution may not contain the word 'zip'. This is to prevent you from just using the built-in zip function."

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

I believe OP's question comes from this site (https://pythonprinciples.com/challenges/Custom-zip/), since I was working through challenges on the same site, and that's how I found this question upon a google search.

I was able to solve the question. To solve it, you can use a for loop and append value at each iteration to the empty list.

```
def zap(a,b):
k=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if i==j:
            k.append((a[i],b[j]))
return k
```

Since the length of the two input lists is the same, you can use i==j to pick element of the same index from both input lists a,b and append it to the empty list k.

Comment: Ok, that works, but is there a reason for the nested for-loops? Wouldn't it be enough to have just one for loop, and one index variable i? Probably faster too, since you'd make n repetitions, not n^2

Comment: you're right - we can skip one 'for loop' and even the 'if' conditional actually.

Answer (score -1):

You can use zip and list comprehension.

```
return [(i,x) for i,x in zip(a,b)]
```

Below is an example without zip but with list comprehension

```
return [(a[i],b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: the exercise don´t let you use the zip built-in function

Comment: Also fifufu if this helped it would be appreciated if you check it.